# Using GROUP_CONCAT output for subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I'm running into a problem, I have the following line in my query

```
CONCAT('',
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trips_loads_rel.load_id,'') AS x 
      FROM `trips_loads_rel` WHERE trips_loads_rel.trip_id = trips.Id)
) AS loads
```

It shows something like `8,10,27` (ie, numeric IDs), some Ids from `trips_loads_rel` table. It works ok. However, how can I use that output to pull matching records from other table? I mean, the line shows me all ids ok, but I need to query other table with these to pull related records. Actually I don't need these IDs, I need their matching records...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <other_table> WHERE <other_table>.load_id IN(CONCAT('',
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trips_loads_rel.load_id,'') AS x 
    FROM `trips_loads_rel` WHERE trips_loads_rel.trip_id = trips.Id)
) AS loads)
```

Comment: Ok! Almost there, thanks for the code. I did the following which half works: it shows the correct stuff once, then it repeats the same as many IDs in the CSV...: SELECT trips.Id, GROUP_CONCAT('', (SELECT loads.load_id FROM `loads` WHERE loads.Id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(trips_loads_rel.load_id,'') AS tmp FROM `trips_loads_rel` WHERE trips_loads_rel.trip_id = trips.Id))) AS loads FROM `trips` GROUP BY trips.Id

Comment: Sorry...just tried, if I put DISTINCT in first GROUP_CONCAT it shows only one result. For instance "L131119-27", one of the load's IDs, where it should be like L131119-27, L131119-21, etc ie, as many loads IDs as matching :( without DISTINCT it just repeats "L131119-27" as it is the first match

Comment: ok try this one:
DISTINCT(GROUP_CONCAT(trips_loads_rel.load_id))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a part of a query, not an entire one, so hard to show exact syntax, but if you want to use the values to find other rows, just don't group concat them to begin with.

Instead just use them directly doing something like;

```
SELECT * FROM `other_table` WHERE `other_table`.`load_id` IN
  (SELECT `load_id` FROM `trips_loads_rel` WHERE `trip_id` = `trips`.`Id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET(col, 'csv as string')` function to get the desired results.

***Example***:

```
mysql> select find_in_set( 2, '11,12,13,14,15,2' );
+--------------------------------------+
| find_in_set( 2, '11,12,13,14,15,2' ) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    6 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select find_in_set( 2, '2,11,12,13,14,15,2' );
+----------------------------------------+
| find_in_set( 2, '2,11,12,13,14,15,2' ) |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> Select FIND_IN_SET( 6, '1,12,3,14,5,16,7,18,9,0,2,13,4,15,6,17,8' );
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET( 6, '1,12,3,14,5,16,7,18,9,0,2,13,4,15,6,17,8' ) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           15 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

For your query you can pass the concatenated output `'8,10,27'` to compare with other_table's column.

```
Select find_in_set( other_table.col_name, '8,10,27' );
```

***Refer To***:
[**MySQL String Functions: FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)